# Condition inside pure function

Tags: core-language, conditional, pure-function

Why condition `/;` not work inside pure function?
Suppose we have:

```
g[x_, y_] := x /; y > 0;
g[1, 3] -> 1
g[1, -3] -> g[1, -3]
```

I need a pure function with the same behavior.
I thought it was a syntax error, but none of it works:

```
g1 = (#1 /; #2 > 0) &;
g2 = #1 /; #2 > 0 &;
g3 = #1 /; (#2 > 0) &;
```

Expected:

```
g1[1, 3] -> 1
g1[1, -3] -> g1[1, -3]
```

Comment: These work fine: `2 /. g1[x_, x - 2] :> 2 x` and
`1 /. g1[x_, x - 2] :> 2 x` -- What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I need only pure function! Edits added

Comment: `Condition` creates a pattern. It does not evaluate to something else.  It operates semantically only in situations where patterns are applied, such as `ReplaceAll` + `Rule`, `Cases`, `Set` / `SetDelayed`. `Function` does not apply patterns.

Comment: But it works for ordinary function?

Comment: Note there are three different meanings of `Condition` in the docs.  `x /; y > 0` is the first kind. Something like `g4[x_, y_] := x /; y > 0`, which I assume you're talking about, is the third kind. It creates a rule of the second kind stored in `DownValues[g4]`. There's a further meaning described in the "Details" section. -- FWIW, I've wished for, as have others, a way to make `Function` application conditional in the way you seek. If you look into it deep enough, you realize that `Function` does not work the way a pattern-based rewrite rule like `g4[x_, y_] :=...` does.

Comment: According to the rules of evaluation, `g1[1, -3]` becomes `(#1 /; #2 > 0) &[1, -3]` because heads are always evaluated and evaluated first. There's no way for it to stay `g1[1, -3]`.

Comment: Is there a problem you're working on in which `g1 = ...&;` seems a more desirable solution than `g[x_, y_] := ...`? If you want `g1[1, -3]` to remain unevaluated, I don't see an advantage to using `Function` instead of the other. But maybe you do?

Comment: @MichaelE2, this is for CodeGolf 8) So pure functions is preferable. I think I use ‵If‵

Comment: I get it. Good luck :)

Comment: Maybe you could use this hack: `g = {#1, #2} /. {x_, y_} :> x /; y > 0 &`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As supplement of @MichaelE2's comment. `Condition` is bit of "meta" in the sense that it will only be absorbed by specific functions with pattern matching features. And the order of evaluation also matters.

Similar to `Condition`, `RuleCondition` can partially satisfy your requirement.

```
RuleCondition[#1,#2>0]&[1,1]
(*1*)
RuleCondition[#1,#2>0]&[1,-1]
(*Fail*)
```