# Numerical Galerkin method with parametrized interpolation function

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, interpolation

**modified**

Here I try to realize a numerical fit (Galerkin method) using parametrized Interpolation function to fit examplary `Exp[x]` in a given grid. So far I tried

```
galerkin =.
galerkin[xii_List (* Grid*)] := 
Block[{yi = Array[y, Length[xii]], ipB, mini, J}
,
ipB = Function[{yi},Interpolation[Transpose[{Rationalize[xii], yi}]]] ;

J = Function[yi,NIntegrate[(ipB[yi][x] - Exp[x])^2, {x, Min[xii], Max[xii]},Method -> { "InterpolationPointsSubdivision", SymbolicProcessing -> 0} ]  ];
mini = NMinimize[J[yi], yi]   // Quiet (*Fehlermeldung ignorierbar*) ;
ipB[yi /. mini [[2]] ]
```

]

Function `galerkin` returns the optimal Interpolation and works quite well  (unfortunately a little slow)

```
grid=Subdivide[0, 1, 10]
Plot[Evaluate[{Exp[x], galerkin[grid][x]}], {x, Min[grid], Max[grid]},PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Black, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

In this version I need `Quiet` command, probably because the definition of `J` isn't restricted to numerical input.

I tried without success `J = Function[yi,NIntegrate[(ipB[yi][x] - Exp[x])^2, {x, Min[xii], Max[xii]},Method -> { "InterpolationPointsSubdivision", SymbolicProcessing -> 0} ]  /; (VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)]`

@xzczd stated in his comment , this form isn't allowed.

Alternatively I tried without success

```
J[yi_ /; (VectorQ[#, NumericQ] & )] := 
NIntegrate[(ipB[yi][x] - Exp[x])^2, {x, Min[xii], Max[xii]}, 
Method -> { "InterpolationPointsSubdivision",SymbolicProcessing -> 0} ]
```

My questions

- What's wrong in my  definition `J`?
- Correct definition of `J`?
- How could I improve the speed of program `galerkin`?

Thanks!

Comment: (-1) 1. Please re-read this question of yours carefully: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203464/1871 See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/285660/1871 There should be more. 2. The last question is quite different from the former two quesitons, please avoid asking distinctly different questions in one post.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks  for reminding me on this question. I don't understand your downvote. Usually a positve answer is much more helpful.

Comment: Because 1. I don't see enough effort in this question. As mentioned in my last comment, the first 2 questions are essentially the same question you asked 3 years ago, which suggests you haven't put enough effort in understanding the answer you've received. 2. The question doesn't meet the standard of this site. (Asking distinctly different questions in one post is enough for a closing vote. ) To sum up, this isn't a post that a 5-year member should post.

Comment: See also: 1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91180/1871 2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/1871 And, please notice definition of `galerkin` cannot be cleared with `galerkin =.`, because it's a function based on pattern matching.

Comment: @xzczd As before, I find your  comments completely dispensable. There exists many questions which additionaly ask for performance issues, no need to ask a new question. By the way only your first link is a question I posted. Which efforts I made the last years can certainly be judged from my many contributions in recent years, but surely not from one question.

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't see enough effort **in this question**, and I'm not talking about your effort in answering questions. The links are all references for you, once you've understood them (esp. the last two links), you should be able to figure out what's wrong with your code. And, please read the document of `PatternTest` (`_?`) and `Condition` (`/;`) carefully, your usage of `/;` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @xzczd The definition `fkt[xi_ /; (VectorQ[#, NumericQ] & )] := xi . xi` works as expected and only evaluates if argument is a numerical list!

Comment: I bet you haven't `Clear[fkt]`. As mentioned above, `fkt=.` won't clear the function definition.