# PatternTest in Function

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, core-language, functional-style

This is probably trivial and already asked but I did not find it.

How to use [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html?q=PatternTest) inside `Function` (`g`) or in pure function (`h`) so that it provides the same result as `f`?

```
Clear[f, g, h, a]

f[x_?NumericQ] := x^2
g = Function[x, x^2];
h = #^2 &;

f /@ {3, a}
g /@ {3, a}
h /@ {3, a}
```

---

```
{9, f[a]}

{9, a^2}

{9, a^2}
```

Comment: I believe there doesn't a straightforward way for the task. `PatternTest` is part of the pattern-matching system of _Mathematica_, so there's no position for it in pure function. (`g = Function[x, x^2];` and `h = #^2 &;` are both pure functions, BTW. `#^2 &` is equivalent to `Function[#^2]`. ) Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/726/1871

Comment: @xzczd I know they are equivalent but the form they are written in is not the same. If `?` cannot be used inside `Function` can `/;` be used to do the same job?

Comment: `Condition` (`/;`) is also part of the pattern-matching system, so I believe it cannot be used in pure function in a straightforward manner, either. (Update: Aha, `Condition` in pure function is asked before: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203464/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/285660/1871 )

Comment: @xzczd Never seen `RuleCondition` before. There is even missing any documentation on it.

Comment: Yeah it's undocumented, but used quite a bit in advanced evaluation order control. You can find examples in this site.

Answer (score 4):

```
h = If[NumericQ[#], #^2, HoldForm[h][#]] &;

h /@ {3, a}
```

> {9, h[a]}

```
g = If[NumericQ[#], Function[x, x^2][#], HoldForm[g][#]] &;

g /@ {3, a}
```

> {9, g[a]}

Comment: Yes, nice but I hoped for a simpler syntax.